# Is there a better way to use animations created by artists in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

Currently I am working with a collada file with animations from the artist. I want to be able to trigger parts of the animation using buttons in my page.
Should I be using collada or a different type?
It seems like there is not a lot of information about how the KeyFrameAnimations are used on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpose of the COLLADA format is transport between software in the production pipeline. It has emphasis on extensibility and simplicity but not efficiency. There are more rational formats, for example, [IQM](https://github.com/lsalzman/iqm)  for skeletal animation. But you should look at what your engine supports and how performance, usability and effort should be balanced.  If you have time you can make your own specialized format or if you can get away  with using COLLADA than use it - it will take less effort and you can easily extend it.